# use barcodeScanner in cordova (with angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, cordova

(I'm fr)
I'm trying to use barcodeScanner in my cordova (works with angularjs) app but it seems my code can't works. I'd like to understand what should I do. :c

First I do :

```
cordova plugin rm https://github.com/wildabeast/Barcode
cordova plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/Barcode
```

Then, here is my code :
**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="BarcodeCtrl">
    <header class="header unSelectable">
        <a ng-click="panel=0" ng-hide="panel==0"><img src="img/back1.png" class="backLogo"></a>
        <!--<img src="img/logo.png" class="logoHeader">-->
        <a ng-click="callBarcodeScanner()"><img src="img/barcode.png" class="barcodeScanner"></a>
    </header>

    <section ng-view class="container">
    </section>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}, false);

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'})
    .when('/list', {templateUrl: 'partials/list.html'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
});

app.controller('BarcodeCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.panel = 0;

    $scope.callBarcodeScanner = function(){
        $('.barCode').val('Scan en cours ...');
        barcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData){
            alert(imageData.text);
            console.log("Barcode Format -> " + imageData.format);
            console.log("Cancelled -> " + imageData.cancelled);
        }, function(error){
            console.log("An error happened -> " + error);
        });
    };
});

$('.barCode').focus(function(){
    $('.barCode').val('');
});
```

If someone can help me...

Comment: The code doesn't work.. 
On my web_browser barodeScanner isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

Finally..
To make the plugin operational, I've to include cordova.js (it doesn't matter if the include fail on the web browser) and use ng-Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Your call looks different than the example provided. You're omitting cordova.plugins

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
  }, 
  function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  }
```

);

Comment: Yea, i didn't notice it in my previous post but I already tested some differents calls.
When I use `cordova.plugins`, I've an error : `cordova is not defined`